# Capturing Attendee Information using Cartthrob 2.5 and EE 2.9

Tags: cartthrob, ee2.9.2

Has anyone had any luck adding the ability to capture attendee information, (i.e. name, company) as part of the Cartthrob 2.5 checkout with EE 2.9?

We're stuck and can't upgrade and would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

CT allows adding custom data to orders via this method:

https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/tutorials/adding_custom_data_to_purchased_items_and_orders/index.html

That should work with CT 2.5, but if not, you can go to the latest CT for EE2 (2.71) and it definitely works there!

Comment: we added custom fields to the cart, but they wouldn't pass thru to the order ?

Comment: @EricG check that you have custom fields set up and that your naming of the inputs matches the custom field names as specified on that link above. It might also be worth upgrading to 2.71 for EE2.

Comment: thanks, we'll try that! Don't suppose you know where we could download CT 2.71?